# expo-in-app-purchases `connectAsync` not resolving for App Store reviewers

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, app-store, expo

We have a react-native app to which we have just added in-app purchases using the expo-in-app-purchases package. Everything seems to be working when testing development builds and TestFlight-distributed release builds on our own devices.

However, we find that the app is consistently *not* working when reviewed by App Store reviewers.

In the latest review, via our error logging mechanism we discovered that the following error was thrown:

["Must wait for promise to resolve before recalling function."](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-in-app-purchases/ios/EXInAppPurchases/EXInAppPurchasesModule.m#L291)

This was thrown because during review the reviewer caused the following code to be executed twice, 7 minutes apart:

```
import { getProductsAsync } from 'expo-in-app-purchases';

...

const { responseCode, results } = await getProductsAsync(iOSProductIdArray));
```

It turns out the initial call to `getProductsAsync` never resolved, meaning when we called it again, some logic in expo-in-app-purchases (linked above) threw an error.

But what we don't know is *why* that method doesn't resolve when Apple reviewers use our app, when it always works when we do. The reviewers are signing in to the iTunes Store using the same sandbox credentials we use, and using the same build that we use, but are never able to load product details, which means they can never view purchase options in-app.

Is there something special about the review environment that prevents this function from working? We have theorised that `InAppPurchases.connectAsync()`, which we call when the app first boots, is failing for reviewers, but we have no idea how or why. Does anyone know how the review environment or process could cause this?

Comment: This _may_ specifically be a problem with the Apple Review environment. There is an issue, which has been documented and acknowledged by Apple engineers - see https://twitter.com/JPEGuin/status/1174217758604705792 - that only happens during Apple Review, when SKProductsRequest is called, which is what getProductsAsync calls under the hood. I will update if this turns out to be our problem.

Comment: FWIW, we resolved this, but I don't know what the problem actually was. We were missing some information from our paid apps agreement. We added that info and asked for a re-review, and the problem was still present. We then took in-app purchases out of our build and passed review, then we put them back in and submitted again for review, and this time there was no problem. Either we had to submit a whole new build to 'flush' the issue created by the missing metadata or essentially this was an internal Apple hiccup that fixed itself...